# How to add category post count in main navigation menu

Tags: posts, menus, count

Can you guys can help me on how to add/show the post count for category in main menu.
eg: Web Design (10) | Typography (12) | Inspiration (10) | Business (19)

I’m using Hueman & Hueman child theme. Can you guide me which file and code I should change.

This image shows what I have and my need: 
http://designtutor.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/test.png

Website: http://designtutor.org/

Comment: If you're not familiar with WordPress it may be better to find a freelancer. The main thing here is that it probably lies in `header.php` but unfortunately it looks like it's generated with `wp_nav_menu()`. You could probably convert this to `wp_list_categories()` which has a `show_count` parameter built in, otherwise you'll have to create a [wp_nav_menu() Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)

Comment: yes you are correct!  it's generated with wp_nav_menu().
Here is the code. is there any way I can alter this?

<div class="nav-wrap container"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'header','menu_class'=>'nav container-inner group','container'=>'','menu_id' => '','fallback_cb'=> false)); ?></div>

Comment: Please, edit your post to add this information. Have you tried the below answer? That ended up working for me.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved many ways. But, the below method is most prominent to me.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'wpse165333_the_title', 10, 2);
function wpse165333_the_title($title, $post_ID)
{
    if( 'nav_menu_item' == get_post_type($post_ID) )
    {
        if( 'taxonomy' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_type', true) && 'category' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object', true) )
        {
            $category = get_category( get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true) );
            $title .= sprintf(' (%d)', $category->count);
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

> Note: `$category->count` doesn't always contain the proper value of
>   posts. In case any other CPT is using `category` as taxonomy, the
>   count would be combination of posts and CPTs.
>
> Usage: The code should go on your child theme's `functions.php` file
>   (if exists), or the parent theme's `functions.php` file or either in a
>   plugin.